# Enter Data into Cell in UITableview

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a small amount of data to show in a table and so I would like to load it all.  Below is my code and for some reason nothing is showing up.  Can you please have a look at what I have done wrong.  Thanks

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"S%1dR%1d",indexPath.section,indexPath.row];

TableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[TableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

// Configure the cell...

long row = [indexPath row];

cell.BBname.text = _BBNames [row];
cell.BBtype.text = _BBTypes [row];
cell.BBimage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:_BBImages [row]];

if([self getCheckedForIndex:indexPath.row]==YES)
{
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
}

return cell;}
```

Comment: Don't make a different Cell Identifier for each row!! Why are you doing that??

Comment: Also… row is an NSInteger, not a long.

Answer (score 1):

is "TableViewCell" your custom cell?
if not use "UITableViewCell" instead

if you are using interface builder for your custom cell, use initializer

```
 [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed: owner: options:]
```

also make sure your tableview delegate is set, specifically implement

```
 - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```